# Making the "active part" or "view" of the map smaller than the actual height of the map in leaflet?

Tags: css, leaflet, jsx, react-leaflet

I am making a navigation app in react-leaflet. I would like the design to be styled so that the search bar is on top of the map like so:

*as I have no reputation I cannot post the image, sorry...*

https://github.com/lyoungblood14/myrepo1/blob/main/annotation.png

However, as you can see from the situation, this of course causes the leaflet controls to overlay the search bar. This has: a parent `.page-div`, and three siblings `.search-div`, `.map-div`, and `.info-div` [currently not visible]. The parent `.page-div` has `position: relative`, and the children have `position: absolute`.

This may be able to be solved via Ihttps://groups.google.com/g/leaflet-js/c/rKMZX3PKFuI, but I'm the working more on the styling and don't really know jsx. This solution also seems impossible because I worry that it will cause problems in the long run, i.e. not being able to properly center a leaflet popup on the page.

Is there a way to make the "active part" or "view" of the map smaller than the actual height of the map? For example:

https://github.com/lyoungblood14/myrepo1/blob/main/iPhone%208%20Plus%20-%201.png

This would ideally mean that e.g. a centering function, or showing our routes, the app would center **on the action area**, not the whole map.

EDIT: I'm hoping to explore this...

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/859

Comment: Do read the source code from https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thank you, that looks really promising! A little intimidating as a beginner but I will give it a good go :) many thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved part of my problem in this way:
using leaflet-active-area plugin, I followed @benistary's suggestion [here](https://github.com/Mappy/Leaflet-active-area/issues/43) and added:

```js
return (<div id="map-div">
        <MapContainer
          center={initialCenter}
          zoom={13}
          style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
          zoomControl={false}
          minZoom={8}
        >
          <MapContent></MapContent>
          
          ...OTHER STUFF...
        
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
      )
      
      
      
const MapContent = () => {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Use setActiveArea in useEffect to ensure it runs after the map is initialized
    map?.setActiveArea("activeArea", true, true);
  }, [map]);
}
```

```css
/*style active area*/

.activeArea {
  width: 100%;
  top: 19%;
  position: absolute;
  /* position: sticky; */
  right: 0%;
  min-height: 80%;
  border: 10px blue solid;
  z-index: 5000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The key is that the map should be within MapContainer and you need MapContent to set the active area. It was important that the `const` code comes after the return so the map is initialized first.

However, this does not affect the placement of the leaflet-bar elements...